# How to pre-populate ORMLITE database with json efficiently

Tags: android, json, performance, ormlite

I'm currently workin on an `Android` application, and I have to populate the Ormlite database from a json file which is shipped within the application.

Here's my question : How can I pre-populate the database really fast knowing the file is contaning thousands of items ?

From now, I'm just reading the file and populate the Db via a DbHelper method to save my entity.

Thanks in advance for your answers :)